Excel with misconfigured menu and closing by itself when opening the VBE
In the last few days I have been facing these problems. There are two situations, but they seem to be related.
1 - When I include a module in the VBE, the text on the right menu is misconfigured, as if there were a language or special character problem.
2 - A few seconds after including this module, without executing any command, Excel restarts. No error message appears, it just closes and reopens.
Procedures I have already performed to try to solve the problem:
I reinstalled Office 365, both in 32 and 64 ... the notebook's system type is 64.
I formatted the notebook, and reinstalled Windows 11 again
I restarted in safe mode and checked the add-ins and none are active
I spent a few hours with Microsoft support connected to my notebook to try to solve the problem and they couldn't identify anything
Call number: #7061553767 - the status is as resolved but nothing was resolved, they just tried the same alternatives that I had already done.
What I have been able to identify so far
In the tests, I noticed that when I install Office in English the problem does not occur
If the installation is done in Portuguese or if the language is changed to Portuguese, both problems occur again
I don't know if it helps, but in the Event Log the event 300 appears and the message: Composer Type: 1EXCELP1: %3P2: %4P3: %5P4: %6
Please let me know if you need me to perform more tests or send more information, ok
Thank you very much for your help
Leandro

StackOverflow is an [English-only site]. Please either rewrite your question in English or refer to [pt.so].
